# Is it natural to ask "how many times have you done something" the most?

Tags: grammar

Could you tell me if it's it natural to ask *how many times have you done something the most*? For example:

> How many times have you trained the most in a day?

If it's not natural, is any of the following examples natural?

> What is the most amount of times you have trained in a day.
>
> What is the record amount of times have you trained in a day.

What is the most natural way to ask that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first suggestion sounds awkward to the native speaker. The reason is that the word 'most' is a superlative. It means, 'the greatest amount or number'. It's awkward because there's no indication in the sentence what the things are that are being counted. The listener has to ask, 'The most what?'

You could ask

> How many times have you trained the most of anybody on your team in a day?

You couldn't ask

> How many times have you eaten the most you've ever eaten in your life?

The answer to that is obviously only once, so asking the question doesn't make sense.

Your other two suggestions sound quite normal and natural, except the second one should read, 'you have' instead of 'have you'. You could also ask

> What is the largest number of times you've trained in a day?
> What is the most you've trained in a day?
> What is the record number of times you've trained in a day?

Answer (score 2):

*How many times have you trained the most in a day?*
seems to be asking how many times the person has been the most diligent (in the class, for example).

*What is the most amount of times you have trained in a day?*
would certainly be understood, but we usually speak of the "**largest** amount" and the "**number** of times."

*What is the record amount of times have you trained in a day?*
Replacing "amount" with "number", and changing the order of "have you" produces:

**What is the record number of times you have trained in a day?**
which is natural and idiomatic, as long as people really do train several times a day. Do they, or do they 'do some/go for training'?

If they do, you could also ask,
**What is the greatest number of times you've trained in a day?**

It might be more idiomatic to use the noun:
**At the most, how much training have you done in a day?**

Or to speak of *sessions*:
**At the most, how many training sessions have you done/taken in a day?**

Breaking the sentence in half might be even more natural:
**What's the most you've ever trained: how many times a day?**